# Create Variables To Handle Different Excel Field Headers

Tags: python

In python, I am trying to set up a process that would be able to ingest an excel file and load into a pandas dataframe, then perform some calculations on each row and then export a cleaned up excel file. I will not always receive a standardized file to ingest. Files can have a different number of columns and the column header names will always be different. So one file may have Field1, Field2, Field3 and another may have FieldA, FieldB, FieldC. The end-to-end process will not process multiple files at once, so I will not load in multiple files during one single run. I would trigger different runs for each file that I receive. Is there some easy way for me to easily rename column headers in the excel files to column headers in my dataframe? So for example can I easily say that for File 1, map raw excel column Field1 to the Dataframe column Field_Final1 and also easily say that for File 2, map raw excel column FieldA to Dataframe column Field_Final1. Then in my calculations I can always reference Field_Final1. Ideally, I would be able to contain this mapping in an additional excel config file.

```
**File 1**
Field_Final1 = Field1
Field_Final2 = Field2
Field_Final3 = Field3

**File 2**
Field_Final1 = FieldA
Field_Final2 = FieldB
Field_Final3 = FieldC
```

Comment: [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method on a data frame will take a dictionary or function mapping to rename all the columns in a dataframe you could create a function that handles the logic for your non standard files to then rename the columns as you see fit

Comment: better keep it as nested dictionary `data = {"File 1": {"Field_Final1": "Field1", ...}, ..., "File 2": {"Field_Final1": "FieldA", ...}}` or list of dictionaries `data  = [{"Field_Final1": "Field1", ...}, ..., {"Field_Final1": "FieldA", ...}]` and then use `data[0]` to get fields for first file,

Comment: Thank you this is working for me. I was able to store the mapping in an excel now and then load it into a dictionary.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can store logic for a nested IF statement in an excel file that would create a new column that would tag rows based on less than and greater than signs and then reference it in my python code? For example, if I have a column in my data frame that has values that range from 100 to 1,000,00 and I want to create a new column that would tag rows with "<200", "<2000", "<20000", "<200000", "<=1000000". My current solution is to use the "cut" function and store the bins and labels that I want to apply in an excel. Any other ways to do this?